# cxf how to modify targetNamespace from a wsdl to another

Tags: java, maven, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have two wsdl with different targetnamespace. when i receive a request with the targetnamespace of WSDL(1) I want to convert it to the targetnamespace of WSDL(2) to fill elements in wsdl(2).
 The two wsdl have the same structure instead of the targetnamespace, and the wsdl(2) have elements that not exist in wsdl(1).
 All other elements and operations are the Same.

Any idea how to it in a clean way ?
I generate the Java object of each wsdl using the plugin org.apache.cxf with the goal wsdl2java in my Pom

Comment: I can not see any clear way. You need to check out Interceptors http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html